# Swift change UITextfield subclass value in another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a UItextfield subclass called textfieldEdit where I change the border color of the textfield.

In my viewcontroller where I have textfieldEdit attached to a textfield, I want to be able to change the color of the of the textfield if the user didn't enter a value in the textfield. How can I do this?

textfieldEdit.swift :

```
class textfieldEdit: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let border = CALayer()
    let width =  CGFloat(2.0)

    required init?(coder aDecoder: (NSCoder!)) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.delegate=self;
        border.borderColor = UIColor(red: 225/255, green: 225/255, blue: 225/255, alpha: 100).cgColor

        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    @objc(textFieldDidBeginEditing:) func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextField) {

         border.borderColor = UIColor( red: 116/255, green: 193/255, blue: 166/255, alpha: 100 ).cgColor

         textColor = UIColor( red: 116/255, green: 193/255, blue: 166/255, alpha: 100 )
    }

    @objc(textFieldDidEndEditing:) func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextField) {

        border.borderColor = UIColor(red: 225/255, green: 225/255, blue: 225/255, alpha: 1).cgColor

    }


    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    }

}
```

RegisterViewController:

```
class RegisterVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // declare UI objects
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTxt: textfieldEdit!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var fullnameTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var registerBtn: UIButton!


    // first function that is loaded
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



    } // end of viewDidLoad function



    // function that will be performed when clicking the register button
    @IBAction func register_click(_ sender: Any) {

        // if registered button is clicked and textfields are empty
        if usernameTxt.text!.isEmpty   {

            // display red placeholders for empty textfields
            usernameTxt.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Username", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])


        }
```

Comment: can you elaborate what is the problem occurs here ?

Comment: try usernameTxt.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

Comment: Off-topic, but you might want to save yourself (and your potential collaborators) a few headaches down the road by naming **types** (classes, structs, enums, protocols, etc.) in Capital Case (i.e., `TextfieldEdit` or `TextFieldEdit`)

Comment: @KKRocks It's not really a problem I'm having. I just want to add in my RegisterViewController that when usernameTxt.text is empty, I want to make the textfield border that I set in my textFieldEdit subclass to red.

Answer (score 0):

I have edit this code .My code will help you.

```
public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) // became first responder
{
    if (txtCurrent != nil)
    {
       txtCurrent.layer.borderColor =  UIColor(red: 206/255.0, green: 215/255.0, blue: 221/255.0, alpha: 1.000).cgColor
    }

    txtCurrent = textField
    txtCurrent.layer.borderColor =  UIColor(red: 67/255.0, green: 153/255.0, blue: 201/255.0, alpha: 1.000).cgColor

}

public func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{
    txtCurrent.layer.borderColor =  UIColor(red: 206/255.0, green: 215/255.0, blue: 221/255.0, alpha: 1.000).cgColor

}
```

Comment: This is not what I want to do...  just want to add in my RegisterViewController that when usernameTxt.text is empty, I want to make the textfield border that I set in my textFieldEdit subclass to red.

Comment: This doesn;'t help me. I'm trying to reference my textFieldEdit subclass when changing the border color